# Is a minimum of RMSE also a minimum of MAE?

Tags: statistics

Let's assume the *root mean square error* or RMSE of a particular
population of values is given by:

$$RMSE=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n e_i^2}n} $$

while the *mean average error* or MAE is given by:

$$MAE=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n |e_i|}n$$

Here, $e_i$ is $v_i - v_\text{reference}$, and the $v_i$'s are such that they always add up to the same number:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n v_i=V_\text{total}$$

I'd like to know if, under these conditions, a minimum of the RMSE
function, i.e., any set of $n$ values of $v_i$ that minimizes RMSE also
minimizes MAE.

If it's true, how would I go about proving it?

I know that the reverse is *not* true, i.e, for $n=3$, $V_\text{total} = 12$ and $v_\text{reference}=0$, the minimum of MAE is $4$, and is found on both sets
of points:

$$v_1=4, v_2=4, v_3=4$$

and

$$v_1=1, v_2=1, v_3=10$$

But the second set of point does not minimize RMSE.

Comment: Shouldn't the expression for MAE have absolute values?

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry. I missed that in the MathJax edit

Comment: RMSE $\geq$ MAE, and the equality happens when all $e_i$s are equal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Minimization of RMSE** Since $\sum_i e_i^2 = \sum_i (v_i - v_\text{reference})^2 = \sum_i (v_i^2 - 2 v_i v_\text{reference} + v_\text{reference}^2) = \sum_i v_i^2 - 2 v_\text{reference} \sum_i v_i + n v_\text{reference}^2 = \sum_i v_i^2 - 2 v_\text{reference} V_\text{total} + n v_\text{reference}^2$ and $\sum_i v_i^2 = \sum_i (v_i - V_\text{total}/n + V_\text{total}/n)^2 = \sum_i ((v_i - V_\text{total}/n)^2 + 2 v_i V_\text{total}/n + (V_\text{total}/n)^2) = \sum_i (v_i - V_\text{total}/n)^2 + 2 V_\text{total}/n \sum_i (v_i - V_\text{total}/n) + (V_\text{total}/n)^2$, in which the last term does not depend on $v_i$, the middle term is $0$ (as $\sum_i v_i = V_\text{total}$), and the first term is minimized by choosing $v^*_i = V_\text{total}/n$ for all $i$.
2. **Local optimality of $v^*_i$** Let $\delta v_i$ be $n$ numbers such that $\sum_i \delta v_i = 0$ and all $\delta v_i$ are small enough for $V_\text{total}/n - v_\text{reference}$ and $V_\text{total}/n - v_\text{reference} + \delta v_i$ to have the same sign (so that $|V_\text{total}/n - v_\text{reference} + \delta v_i| = |V_\text{total}/n - v_\text{reference}| + \delta v_i$). For any such $\delta v_i$,
   $\mathrm{MAE}(V_\text{total}/n + \delta v_1, \ldots, V_\text{total}/n + \delta v_n) - \mathrm{MAE}(V_\text{total}/n, \ldots, V_\text{total}/n)$ = $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i (| V_\text{total}/n - v_\text{reference} + \delta v_i| - | V_\text{total}/n - v_\text{reference}|) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \delta v_i = 0\vphantom{dddddd}$, so $v^*_i$ locally minimize MAE.
3. **Global optimality of $v^*_i$** Since MAE as a function of $v_i$ is convex and the equality constraint function $\sum_i v_i - V_\text{total}$ is affine, any local minimum is a global minimum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization#Theory and section 4.2.2 in general http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), the $v^*_i$ that minimize RMSE also minimize MAE.

Comment: I can't really follow your argumentation...how did you derive your line for instance? another remark $ 1 \leq i \leq i/2$ is an empty set.

Comment: $1 \leq i \leq i/2$ was a typo (should have been $n$). What line are you refering to?

Comment: "first" line...miss that myself

Comment: First equation in the first line: $\sum_i e_i^2 = \sum_i (v_i - v_\text{reference})^2 = \sum_i (v_i^2 - 2 v_i v_\text{reference} + v_\text{reference}^2) = \sum_i v_i^2 - 2 v_\text{reference} \sum_i v_i + n v_\text{reference}^2 = \sum_i v_i^2 - 2 v_\text{reference} V_\text{total} + n v_\text{reference}^2$.

Comment: Second equation in the first line: $\sum_i v_i^2 = \sum_i (v_i - V_\text{total}/n + V_\text{total}/n)^2 = \sum_i ((v_i - V_\text{total}/n)^2 + 2 v_i V_\text{total}/n + (V_\text{total}/n)^2) = \sum_i (v_i - V_\text{total}/n)^2 + 2 V_\text{total}/n \sum_i (v_i - V_\text{total}/n) + (V_\text{total}/n)^2$. The last term does not depend on $v_i$, the middle term is equal to $0$ (since $\sum_i v_i = V_\text{total}$) and the first term is minimized by setting $v_i - V_\text{total}/n = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Budenn, I'm having trouble following too. I can understand the first line. It says a constant distribution minimizes both MAE and RMSE. The second statement I don't quite understand. But mostly it is the third statement which I don't understand: you seem to imply there is a distribution of $v_i$ that minimizes RMSE but not MAE, thus disproving my hypothesis. Can you give a concrete example of $v_i$'s and $v_\text{reference}$?

Comment: @Budden, the last premise looks fishy: take $v_\text{reference}=0$, $n=8$,  and $V_\text{total} = 8$. Now take $u=0$. This $u$ is in your conditions and the distribution is ${0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2}$. MAE is 1 which is *not* lower than the MAE for $v^*_i$, which are ${1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}$.

Comment: @JoaoTavora, the last premise is indeed wrong, but for slightly different reason: there are no $u$ such that both $u \in \left(\frac{V_\text{total}}{n} - \left| \frac{V_\text{total}}{n} - v_\text{reference} \right| , \frac{V_\text{total}}{n}\right)$ and $u < v_\text{reference} < 2 \frac{V_\text{total}}{n} - u$. In your example, $u < v_\text{reference}$ does not hold (it falls under the second statement).

Comment: @Budden, yeah, I noticed that too, so I assumed you meant $<=$... You edited your answer, it's become slightly more confusing :-). Before attempting proof, can you say clearly if you confirm or disprove my hypothesis?

Comment: I confirm your hypothesis.

Comment: It looks good now, if a bit complicated. But it's more than I could achieve, and I understand the first 2 points. For the third, I'll have to read up on those concepts. I've accepted it. Thanks!